# Sigmaplot: How to scale x-axis for correctly displaying boxplots

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, boxplot

I want to display overlapping boxplots using Sigmaplot 12. When I choose the scale for the x-axis as *linear* then the boxes do indeed overlap but are much too thin. See figure below. Of course they should be much wider.

[image: too_thin]

When I choose the scale of the x-axis to be "category", then the boxes have the right width, but are arranged along each single x-value.

[image: wrong_position]

I want the position as in figure 1 and the width as in figure 2. I tried to resize the box in figure 1 but when I choose 100% in "bar width" than it still looks like Figure 1.

many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, I found the answer myself. In Sigmaplot, there is often the need to prepare "style"-columns, for example if you want to color your barcharts, you need a column that holds the specific color names.

For my boxplot example I needed a column that has the values for "width". These had to be quite large (2000) in order to have an effect. Why ?  I have no idea. First I thought it would be because of the latitude values and that the program interprets the point as "1.000"s, but when I changed to values without decimals, it didn´t get better.

Well, here is the result in color. 
Have fun !

[image]